# Find duplicated rows between multiple same tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with the same schema:

```
dbo.orders_1
| user_id | order_id | create_time             |
|---------|----------|-------------------------|
| 1       | 5        | 2018-05-04 02:26:03.808 |
| 1       | 6        | 2021-01-01 02:26:03.821 |
| 2       | 12       | 2021-12-12 02:26:03.814 |

dbo.orders_2
| user_id | order_id | create_time             |
|---------|----------|-------------------------|
| 6       | 7        | 2020-06-04 02:26:03.808 |
| 1       | 5        | 2021-01-01 02:26:03.821 |
| 3       | 4        | 2021-12-12 02:26:03.814 |
```

This is how I can find duplicated rows between two tables:

```sql
select 
  a.user_id, 
  a.order_id, 
  a.create_time as "create_time_1", 
  b.create_time as "create_time_2"
from 
  orders_1 a 
  join orders_2 b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
  and a.order_id = b.order_id
```

Which gives me this output:

```
| user_id | order_id | create_time_1           | create_time_2           |
|---------|----------|-------------------------|-------------------------|
| 1       | 5        | 2020-06-04 02:26:03.808 | 2021-01-01 02:26:03.821 |
```

It works, but now I added another table:

```
dbo.orders_3
| user_id | order_id | create_time             |
|---------|----------|-------------------------|
| 77      | 2        | 2015-09-15 02:26:03.808 |
| 3       | 4        | 2018-04-15 02:26:03.814 |
```

I want to find any duplicates in those 3 tables. What I expect is:

```
| user_id | order_id | create_time_1           | create_time_2           | create_time_3           |
|---------|----------|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|
| 1       | 5        | 2020-06-04 02:26:03.808 | 2021-01-01 02:26:03.821 | NULL                    |
| 3       | 4        | NULL                    | 2021-12-12 02:26:03.814 | 2018-04-15 02:26:03.814 |
```

What should sql look like? https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/7f31a47ef4c633ad8b4ba88a4276964d/

I thought this might work:

```sql
select 
  a.user_id, 
  a.order_id, 
  a.create_time as "create_time_1", 
  b.create_time as "create_time_2",
  c.create_time as "create_time_3"
from 
  orders_1 a 
  join orders_2 b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
  and a.order_id = b.order_id
  left join orders_3 c on a.user_id = c.user_id
  and a.order_id = c.order_Id
```

but this gives me nothing in `create_time_3` column

Comment: How `user_id =3 order_id = 4` made it to the final expected output?

Comment: @PankajSanwal I've updated an question. It comes from second and third table

Comment: @PankajSanwal do you need to check table 3 with table 1 as well?

Comment: @learning Yes, I want to find any duplicated record between those 3 tables

Comment: @learning duplicate can be between tables 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3, or 1 and 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just missing one of the potential duplicate cases (you have 1>2,1>3 but not 2>3). If you need to check for duplicates across each of the tables, you need to include another join:

```
select 
  a.user_id, 
  a.order_id, 
  a.create_time as "create_time_1", 
  b.create_time as "create_time_2",
  coalesce(c.create_time,d.create_time) as "create_time_3"
from 
  orders_1 a 
  join orders_2 b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
  and a.order_id = b.order_id
  left join orders_3 c on a.user_id = c.user_id
  and a.order_id = c.order_Id
  left join orders_3 d on b.user_id = d.user_id
  and b.order_id = d.order_Id
```

If you need to know between which two tables the duplicates occurred, you need to split out the columns.